# Reverse sloped driveway questions

Tags: garage, driveway, slope

I am looking at a house with a reverse sloped driveway. Are there always going to be a lot of maintenance issues with keeping drains cleared, making sure that the drain is not frozen in the winter to prevent flooding, etc.? If I were to buy the house with the slope, are there any best practices to minimize maintenance and the risk of flooding, whilst keeping the sloped driveway?

Do homeowners ever just fill in the reverse slope and get rid of the underground garage essentially? Is it a fairly easy DIY job? I would be open to doing that, just not sure if there are any structural issues that might introduce by filling with dirt and just basically covering the garage.

Edit: Here's a picture of the sloped driveway:

[image: Picture 1 of slope]
[image: Picture 2 of slope]

Thanks

Comment: Getting the car out becomes *much* harder.

Comment: Can you post a picture? It would be helpful just to see all the details and provide the best solution

Comment: Agreed, I can imagine getting out of the driveway would be  a nightmare. I wonder if just filling it in would be the way to go. I just posted a couple of pictures.

Comment: I am guessing you don't own both buildings if buying the house.  Then filling it and regrading becomes a legal/inspection issue too.